# How can I change XFce4 theme from text (no GUI) console?

Tags: xfce, theme

I would like to **change the default theme** in my XFce4 from `Greybird` to `Daloa`, but for several reasons I need to do it via **remote SSH console** (text, no GUI).

I have tested:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Daloa
```

but I get this error message:

```
Fail when starting libxfconf: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11.
```

I have tried:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Daloa :0
sudo xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Daloa :0
```

... with same results.

How could I **change or configure to change on next user logon the theme** from `Greybird` to `Daloa` in XFce4, assuming I have no `DISPLAY` active that could allow the execution of `xfce...` tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a dbus session manually by issuing the command:

```
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
```

this will set the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID` (as well as others). You should now be able to run the `xfconf-query` command.

After you are done, you can "logout" of this session with:

```
kill -HUP $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
```

Answer (score 1):

To change theme **for your session**, just **edit the XFwm configuration file** named **xfwm4.xml** and change `Greybird` with `Daloa`.
Using `sed` you could simply do:

```
sed -i 's/Greybird/Daloa/' ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml
```

This will be effective the next time you logon to GUI.

To change it **for default new users** starting GUI, the file is at `/etc`:

```
sed -i 's/Greybird/Daloa/' /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml
```